# How can I access device configuration from an EFENTO COAP loader on a server?

Tags: server, iot, coap

I have access to COAP server. I want to change a device configuration. I dont see any API path where i can post the certain device configuration. The documentation only provides tutorial for using EFENTO cloud.

Any clue about the API path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the new configuration in the payload (JSON) of the HTTP response sent to Efento CoAP loader by your application. The documentation is here: https://getefento.com/library/efento-nbiot-sensors-coap-loader-integration/ in section titled "Changing sensor’s settings"